# Own build with 28byj-48 motors, 1.4reprap, Arduino mega, how to "Marlin" the settings !-)

Tags: marlin

seeking advise 
How do I set "marlin" to Operate 28BYJ-48 steppers on all axis?

Thanking you Kindly

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. Normally, it is sufficient to adjust the reference voltages on the stepper motor drivers so that they deliver the required current for each motor. No firmware changes are required at all (unless your driver currents can be controlled by firmware). Of course, if you have a completely non-standard build, you may need to change the Marlin header file so that the correct microcontroller pins (and other things) are used. Although you indicate that you are using an Arduino Mega, you do not say what controller board you are using (unless it is RAMPS 1.4).

Comment: Also, you need to state what stepper-motor drivers you are using.